# Using a js cookie to remember objects position when the page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, animation, cookies, css-position

Okay. So the code pasted below is another update. What I am trying to do is use a cookie to store the position of an object which changes it's position based on two buttons (DIVs actually).

The `createCookie` and `readCookie` are basically copy and pasted.

The `checkCookie` and `storeCookie` are doing most of the functionality I'm looking for (remembering cookie & checking on page load).

The `$(document).ready(function()` is the position control using jquery.

```
<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>
////////////////////////FROM QUIRKSMODE.ORG///////////////////////////////
//equivalent of "setCookie" from w3schools
//time is represented in days*hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}
//equivalent of "getCookie" from w3schools
function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

///////////////////////////cookie functions////////////////////////////////
var pos=readCookie("position");
//var object = document.getElementById('CWS_flow_001');

function checkCookie()
{   
    var object = document.getElementById('CWS_flow_001');

    if (pos=378)
    {
        object.style.position="absolute";
        object.style.left = 378;
        $("#show_primary_rec_001").fadeIn(500);
        $("#show_secondary_rec_002").fadeOut(500);
    }
    else if (pos=-990)
    {
        object.style.position="absolute";
        object.style.left = -990;
        $("#show_primary_rec_001").fadeOut(500);
        $("#show_secondary_rec_002").fadeIn(500);
    }
}
function storeCookie()
{
    //var pos=readCookie("position");
    createCookie("position",pos,1*24*60*60*1000);
    alert("the cookie is set to " + pos);
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

////////////////////////animation of object/////////////////////////////////
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#show_secondary_rec_002").fadeOut(0);


   $("#show_primary_rec_001").click(function moveLeft () {
     $("#CWS_flow_001").animate({
             left: "-990px"
      }, 500 );
     $("#show_primary_rec_001").fadeOut(500);
     $("#show_secondary_rec_002").fadeIn(500);
     //sets "pos" to -990 and runs storeCookie on click w/ 1 second delay
     pos=-990;
     setTimeout("storeCookie()", 1000);
    });

      $("#show_secondary_rec_002").click(function moveRight () {
        $("#CWS_flow_001").animate({
             left: "378px" 
         }, 500 );
     $("#show_primary_rec_001").fadeIn(500);
     $("#show_secondary_rec_002").fadeOut(500);
     //sets "pos" to 378 and runs storeCookie on click w/ 1 second delay
     pos=378;
     setTimeout("storeCookie()", 1000);
    });

 });
 </SCRIPT>
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Thanks for the response Zim48. Sorry for really being clear, I'm a little in over my head with this. I've updated my code since my original post.

Comment: @Zim84 My question: What is the logic I need to do the first part of the function if the cookie is saved as -990 and the second part of the function otherwise (i.e. remember the cookie).

Comment: I believe all that I'm missing is the correct [code]if[/code] parameters. Something like pseudocode: if (position!=startingPosition) {object.style.left = saved cookie position;}. Hopefully that makes some sense...

Comment: perhapes I'm also *a little in over my head* (whatever that means), but... I still don't understand: what do you want, where is the problem and what is the question that derives from that?

Comment: First, thanks for bearing with me. So...I want to have the cookie "pos" stored when the position of my object is changed via click and then return to whatever position was stored on next page load.

Comment: Right now, when I click my 'button', I am getting the alert letting me know that it has reached my 'storeCookie' function, but it will not return to that position on the next page load. In theory, it should use my 'checkCookie' function to move to whichever position is stored (either pos=378 or pos=990).